# PHP: url parameters

Tags: php, redirect, get, string-formatting

i have a question about formatting the URL parameters in php

page 1 can have these 2 url

```
http://somewhere.com/page1.php?foo=1
and
http://somewhere.com/page1.php
```

now on page 1, when i click a button, i want it to redirect to its self but with an additional parameters in the URL like so

```
http://somewhere.com/page1.php?foo=1&bar=2
or
http://somewhere.com/page1.php?bar=2
```

depending on the current url. How can i do this in php?

thanks,
Vidhu

Comment: take a look at the output of print_r($_SERVER);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if a certain `$_GET` parameter is set, using `isset`.
If it is, `echo` a certain link.  If not, `echo` a different link.

```
if( !isset($_GET['bar']) ){
    echo '<a href="?bar=2">link</a>';
}
else{
    echo '<a href="page1.php">link</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following form will submit to the same url with parameters added.

```
<form action="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="get">
    <?php
        // Iterate through our query string and add each key value pair as a hidden input
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
        {
            ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"/>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

    <!-- new parameter to add -->
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple get system, So you will need to check if `?foo=1` is set if it is you can echo its content. If you want to show content for `bar=2` check if its set and echo its content. This is just a simple way there more ways though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

For example

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here the [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is used to avoid PHP_SELF exploitation as a security precaution

<del>If you wish to avoid hidden input fields you can append the query parameters like `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?foo=1&bar=2"`</del>

Comment: I thought that would work too, but when you submit the form, the query string in the action is removed.

Comment: @Samuel Ya, its true, its getting replaced. thanks to pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these PHP functions to help me build urls correctly:

- `parse_str()`
- `parse_url()`
- `http_build_query()`
- `http-build-url()`

Example:

```
<?php

function add_parameters($parameters) {
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $old_parameters_as_array);
    return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.http_build_query(array_merge($old_parameters_as_array, $parameters));
}

echo '<a href="'.add_parameters(array('bar' => 2)).'">Link</a>';
```